# Wordpress REST API link shows 403 error

Tags: wordpress

I am using WP REST API in my wordpress blog. I am getting all the post using this link and it works fine. http://www.gmonetix.com/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

But when I want to get a particular post by id such as http://www.gmonetix.com/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1122 , it shows 403: Error -  access to the resource in this server is denied. Please give a solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve single post by id like, this should work,

```
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[p]=1122
```

This URL gives response,

```
http://www.gmonetix.com/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[p]=1122
```

Comment: No this is not working. It is returning 10 posts which will slow down my connections. I want that particular post only.

Comment: Have you read this topic : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/rest-api-get-request-wp-jsonwpv2posts-returns-403-error/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You can try disabling `mod_security` on your server or making an exception for `mod_security` for the REST endpoints. Also you can try WordPress on your local server and confirm issue.